# URL validation should not accept empty string in the beginning

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to validate a URL. It should not contain a space in the beginning and in between. It should throw an error alert if we don't enter a complete URL. For example, if input is `www.google`, it should throw the following exception:

> 'Please enter a complete URL'

Can someone help me out with this?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: Where is your code? What doesn't work? What do you expect?

Comment: What do you consider a complete url?

Comment: Why exactly is `www.google` incomplete? Because it's missing the protocol prefix (`http://`) or because `.google` is not an ICANN-approved TLD?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj a complete url is something like https://www.google.co.in, if i enter https://www.google.   it should alert me with enter complete url  Thanks

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález a complete url is something like google.co.in, if i enter google. it should alert me with enter complete url Thanks

Comment: A complete URL is something with three components? So `google.com` must be rejected?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález a complete url can be with four components like www.google.co.in

Comment: first you need to decide upon what logical criteria defines a valid url, because google.com, www.google.com, www.google.co.in all are valid. Perhaps you want that there must be `www` and after that there must be two or three strings separated by dot?

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you consider something random like `www.efg-cba.asdfgh` a valid domain or not?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj i want http or https in the first and then followed by www and then two or three components followed by it and it should not allow space in the begining and if it don't enter complete url it should alert me Thank You

Comment: ok, then let's say `http://www.efg-cba.asdfgh` is valid? even though it does not exist?

Comment: Take a look at [**What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url).

Comment: So actual sites that do not use a `www` prefix must be rejected? Why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jQuery validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin to ensure valid URL's. Here's some example code taken from [the website](https://jqueryvalidation.org/url-method/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Makes "field" required and a url.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css">



</head>
<body>
<form id="myform">
<label for="field">Required, URL: </label>
<input class="left" id="field" name="field">
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script>
// just for the demos, avoids form submit
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      url: true
    }
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: kadillak  I'm not using bootstrap validator, thanks for the answer

Comment: Why go through all of the work of trying to validate URL's when somebody else has already done it? Also this is not bootstrap validator. This is a standalone jQuery plugin.

Comment: yeah, even i wish that, but i'm not supposed to use third party library, thanks for the suggesstion

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expressions to match the entered string with your pattern. Based on your specification of the url pattern, following example might do it:

```js
var regex = /^(http)s?(:\/\/www)(\.\w{2,}){2,3}$/;

$("#check").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $("#url").val();
  if( regex.test(url) ){
    alert("URL is complete");
  }else{
    alert("Please enter a complete url");
  }
});//#check click()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="url" value="https://www.google.com" />
<button id="check">Validate</button>
```

Comment: Nope, that regex misses a lot

Comment: @Mi-Creativity yeah you're right. Added some improvements but can see now that it misses several things. Thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 0):

> I want `http` or `https` in the first and then followed by `www` and then two or three components followed by it and it should not allow space in the beginning.

**REGEX: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/08BOog/1/)** <sup>(**1**)</sup>

```
^https?:\/\/www\.(?:[a-z0-9]-?)+[^-\.]\.[a-z]{2,15}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?$
```

- **`^https?`** starts with `http` or `https`, hence the **`?`** after the `s` letter.
- **`:\/\/www\.`** matches `://www.` <sup>(**2**)</sup>
- **`(?:`**  starts a non-capturing group.
- **`[a-z0-9]-?`** matches the "name" part of the domain name, only letters and numbers with a possibility of one hyphen **`-`** after and not on the start.
- **`)+[^-\.]`** closes the non-capturing group with the possibility of having more than one occurrence of `[a-z0-9]-?` to match URLs like `http://www.some-domain-name.com`, and it should *not* end with a dot **`.`** or a hyphen **`-`**, hence the `[^-\.]` part.
- **`\.`** matches a dot `.`
- **`[a-z]{2,15}`** is a set of `2` to `15`, letters only, matches the gTLD [[generic top-level domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_top-level_domain)] part of the domain name.
- **`(?:\.[a-z]{2})?$`** ends the regex with a non-capturing group of set of 2 letters only represents the ccTLD [[country code top level domain](https://icannwiki.org/index.php?title=Country_code_top-level_domain)] part, this part may exist or not this why we have **`?`** after the group.

**Code: [jsFiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/aurkbrvr/1/)**

```js
var domains = document.querySelectorAll('#domains-list li'),
  $URLregX = /^https?:\/\/www\.(?:[a-z0-9]-?)+[^-\.]\.[a-z]{2,15}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?$/i;

for (var i = 0, ln = domains.length; i < ln; i++) {
  var th = domains[i],
    urlText = th.innerHTML,
    $span = ($URLregX.test(urlText)) ? ' <span class="matched">Matched</span>' : ' <span class="not-matched">NOT Matched</span>';

  th.innerHTML = urlText + $span;
}
```

```css
*{ padding:0; font-family:verdana, sans-serif; font-size:1em; }
li{ padding: 10px; border-bottom:1px dotted #AAA; }
li:nth-child(even){ background-color:#EEE; }
li span{ color:white; padding:3px 5px; border-radius:3px; font-size:12px; }
.matched{ background-color:green; }
.not-matched{ background-color:darkred; color:white; }
```

```html
<ul id='domains-list'>
  <li>http://www.google.co.sa</li>
  <li>http://WWW.EXAMPLE.NET</li>
  <li>http://www.google.com</li>
  <li>http://www.some-site.engineering</li>
  <li>https://www.google.com</li>
  <li>http://www.efg-cba.asdfgh</li>
  <li>http://maps.google.com</li>
  <li>httphttps://www.example.net</li>
  <li>http://abc.site-name.com</li>
  <li>https://some-sub-domain.exam-ple.musem.uk</li>
  <li>http://google.com</li>
  <li>http://sub-domain.example-site.engineering</li>
  <li>http://test-www.mi-creativity.com</li>
  <li>https://google.co.in</li>
  <li>www.google</li>
  <li>www.google.com</li>
  <li>mail.google.com</li>
  <li>://www.google</li>
  <li>//www.google</li>
  <li>:google.com</li>
  <li>http://www..google.co.sa</li>
  <li>http://www.google..co.uk</li>
  <li>http://www.google.co..uk</li>
  <li>htt:google.com</li>
  <li>http:google.com</li>
  <li>http:/google.com</li>
  <li>http//www.google.com</li>
  <li>http://www.go ogle.com</li>
  <li>http://www.google.c om</li>
  <li>http://www.-google.com </li>
  <li>http://www.g--oogle.com </li>
  <li>http://www.google-.com</li>
  <li>http://www.-google.com</li>
  <li>http://www.g--oogle.com</li>
  <li>http://www.example.c</li>
</ul>
```

> if I don't enter complete URL it should alert me

[**jsFiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/wrde71px/)

---

**Notes:**

1. This regex works for URL written in English only, there could be URLs or TLDs written in languages other than English, like: Arabic, Chinese, Indian, Japanese and Russian, the above regex will not match any of them. [List of top-level domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#ICANN-era_generic_top-level_domains).
2. While sub-domains could be a combination of letters, numbers and a hyphen, the regex checks for `www` only because this is what the OP is asking for, to check for usual possibilities of the sub-domain part, [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/zpvo4X/2/) works for usual sub-domains as well as the case where there's *no* sub-domain like `http://example.com`.